# Passing params through axios post call

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, vue.js, axios

I'm currently using vue-resource to perform some ajax call in my webpack project. As soon as I make "get" calls all works perfectly but when I try a post one my PHP does not get any parameter and if I try to do var_dump($_POST) the result is an empty array.
My code is quite basic :

```
let data = {req: 'req_tipe', ch: 001 };
this.$http.post('compute.php', data).then(response => {
    //do stuff with response if ok             
    },
    response => {
    //do stuff about error
    });
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing

**UPDATE:**
I did the same with axios and vue-axios but my issue still remain:
no post parameters

```
let data = {req: 'req_tipe', ch: 001 };
this.axios.post('compute.php', data).then(response => {
    //do stuff with response if ok             
    },
    response => {
    //do stuff about error
    });
```

Comment: vue-resource has been retired. Replace it with AXIOS.

Comment: here is what I was missing!!

Comment: What were you missing?

Comment: that vue-resource has been retired as M U pointed

Comment: It has been retired but you can still use last version...

Comment: my issue still remain......

Comment: If you're using Chrome, go into the developer tools and watch the Network tab when you make the request.  See if the data is leaving your browser properly.

Comment: Yes, it does. Atm I just found a workaround replacing the post call with a get one.

Comment: It pretty much depends on two things - what is your `Content Type` **AND** if you're making cross origin request? (CORS)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can change like following:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('req','req tipe');
data.append('ch','001');
this.axios.post('compute.php', data).then(response => {
//do stuff with response if ok             
},
response => {
//do stuff about error
})
```

have a try, or see [issues 318](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/318) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you do a POST request with Content-Type "application/json" which is the default in Axios when you send an object as data.

PHPS $_POST only works when the request is sent with application/x-www-form-urlencoded as the content type and the data as a Querystring.

When using a library like qs, the following should work:

```
var qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 });
```

axios automatically uses the right content type when the input data is a querystring.

You also can use the json data, but then you have to change the PHP backend into something like this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Some frameworks like Symphony can handle this automatically.